# Java Network Events

Tags: java, networking, mobile

I am creating a java mobile application and I want to be aware as to when the device obtain an IP address to then be able to send messages to a backend system.

Do any API exists? I guess if an API existed it would have to use system dependant calls thru JNI?

Thank you,
Julien.

Comment: What's you target platform? BlackBerry provides a coverage API, for example.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do but here are a few things that could prove useful:

- stackoverflow has tags for J2ME and javaME, the mobile versions of Java.
- Theorically, installing a MIDlet that declares a static PushRegistry socket connection could force the device to always have an IP address. That would obviously depend on how the Pushregistry spec was interpreted by the VM provider.
- There is no standard JNI support for mobile Java virtual machines.
- A mobile Java application may be automatically paused when it is backgrounded so I'm not convinced you shouldn't just use the GCF API to open a client socket connection to your back-end system. It is presumably only needed when the MIDlet is in the foreground.